# Retrieve a List from NSData, stored as BLOB in SQLite with Core-Data within a Flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, core-data

I'm pretty new to Flutter and hope for some help.
I build an SwiftUI application for iOS with Core-Data. My next step was to build a Flutter app to support iOS and Android for the upcoming version. Therefore I rebuild the whole application.

The nativ iOS app is using Core -Data and I'm saving several things there. For example some Strings and also a list of Double values: `[Double]` (for example `[5.5, 4.3]`.
I was using a Transformable attributeType to store it (also have the valueTransformerName `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName`).

I would like to migrate all the "old" data from the iOS app to my new Flutter app. I was able to load the "old" database within my Flutter app and get all the data and save them to the new database with [Floor](https://pub.dev/packages/floor).
Currently I have troubles to get the values from **[Double]**.

I could use a DB tool to investigate the data in the "old" database. The list is stored as an `BLOB`. I can't see any "useful" values/data in the DB tool.

In my Flutter app I tried to get the content of the column with:

`Uint8List doubleList = (element["ZSHOOTS"] as Uint8List);`

Then I have a list with many items (numbers) (but not mine). I tried to simply **cast** it, but nothing worked.

My question is, how can I retrieve the BLOB value and get my list with Doubles?
In SwiftUI - the native iOS app - everything is working fine. I think SwiftUI is converting my `[Double]` to a `NSData` object and save this in the database as a BLOB. While accessing the attribute in the app it converts it automatically back.
Now I have to do the converting in my Flutter app, but I don't know how :-)

One possibility would be to write the transformation the same way SwiftUI is doing it while accessing the data. But I don't know where to finde the transformation.
Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Comment: It would be easier to keep Core Data around long enough to export the images to some other storage system, than to try to reverse engineer Core Data's use of SQLite and binary encoding.

Comment: Good idea. I wouldn’t delete the old database. 
It’s no image, it’s a list. 
Do you have any ideas where to find the binary encoding from Core Data?

Comment: @Alienuser I have to do a similar feature (substitute native iOS app by new Flutter app and migrate from realm to sqflite db). Could you tell me how did you do? I'm trying to create a swift plugin to export all realm info in json format, but I have problems to accomplish. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is an object-graph management system that also provides data persistence. It’s not a object relational mapping framework. While one of the store types is SQLite, the way an object graph is persisted is an implementation detail that is private to Core Data.

This means Core Data is free to persist your object graph however it sees fit, including by storing properties as blobs or other data types that may only make sense to the Core Data framework.

IOW, this is happening at the Core Data level, not SwiftUI level.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
But how can I retrieve the BLOB data and get my list back? Or how can I check how the data is stored in SQLite?

Comment: One option would be to create a hybrid application, or a plugin that allows you to open the store with CoreData, then export the data into a separate SQLite database.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data transformable attributes are encoded using `NSCoding`. If you adopt the `NSCoding` protocol-- which means implementing `init(coder:)` and `encode(with coder:)`-- you should be able to instantiate objects using the binary data that Core Data stores in SQLite. You would use the protocol by creating an instance of `NSKeyedUnarchiver` and using functions in that class to de-archive object instances. It would call the `NSCoding` functions, you wouldn't call them directly.

Using `NSCoding` will probably require that you use objects that inherit from `NSObject`. Swift structures and non-`NSObject` classes will be tricky if not impossible to use for this.

If it was me I wouldn't do any of the above. I'd keep Core Data in the app and migrate the data by (1) fetching the data from Core Data so that it creates object instances, and then (2) saving that data in whatever new format I needed. The SQLite schema is undocumented and reverse-engineering Apple's frameworks is almost always a bad idea when they're already giving you a straightforward way to get your data.

Keep in mind that despite similar names, `NSCoding` is unrelated to Swift `Codable`. Data encoded with one cannot be decoded with the other. You can't use `Codable` to decode Core Data's SQLite blobs.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really good chance the data in the `BLOB` column is stored as zlib compressed json, so you should be able to use a compression library to decompress it into a json string that you can more easily manipulate.

If you wanted to verify this is indeed the case, this is how I would do it in Python:

```
import sqlite3
import zlib

db = sqlite3.connect("<DBNAME>.db")
cursor = db.cursor()

for column in cursor.execute('SELECT <BLOB-COLUMN-NAME> FROM <TABLE-NAME> LIMIT 1'):
    print(zlib.decompress(column))
```